# Не работает роутинг на php

Tags: php

Прошу помощи в данном вопросе. У меня есть голосование на сайте, при нажатии на `"результат"` или `"голосовать"` выдает

```
Warning: require_once(W:\domains\shop.php-start.com-master/views/cabinet/vote.php?id=1): failed to open stream: No error in W:\domains\shop.php-start.com-master\controllers\SiteController.php on line 36

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'W:\domains\shop.php-start.com-master/views/cabinet/vote.php?id=1' (include_path='.') in W:\domains\shop.php-start.com-master\controllers\SiteController.php on line 36
```

Это форма с голосованием

```
<form action="vote.php" method="get" target='_blank'>
<!-- указываем в value цифру нужного нам голосования, для которого уже создали файлы //-->
<input type="Hidden" name="id" value="1">
<p><b>Оцените сайт:</b></p>
<input type="Radio" name="vote" value="1" checked>Отлично<br>
<input type="Radio" name="vote" value="2">Хорошо<br>
<input type="Radio" name="vote" value="3">Удовлет.<br>
<input type="Radio" name="vote" value="4">Плохо<br>
<input type="Radio" name="vote" value="5">Очень плохо<br>
<input type="Submit" value=" Голосовать" style="margin-top:10px;">
</form>

<!-- указываем в href после vote.php?id= цифру нужного нам голосования, для которого уже создали файлы //-->
<p><a href='vote.php?id=1' target='_blank'><button>Результаты</button></a></p>
```

Здесь я пытался сделать роутинг

```
public function actionIndexvsite()
    {
        require_once(ROOT . '/views/cabinet/vote.php?id=1');
        return true;
    }
```

Сам файл vote.php вряд ли пригодится, но при необходимости готов скинуть. Буду рад любой помощи.

UPD: добавил файл `vote.php` ниже

```
<?php
// получаем файлы по определенному голосованию
$id =  (int) $_GET['id']; //приводим к целому числу идентификатор голосования
$vote = (int) $_GET['vote']; //приводим к целому числу передаваемое значение голосования

//проверяем, существует ли такое голосование
if (file_exists("$id.dat")) {

$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //получаем ip адрес
$ip_file = file_get_contents("ip$id.dat");//читаем содержимое файла ip адресов и помещаем в строку
$ip_abbr = explode(",", $ip_file);//получаем в массив имеющиеся ip адреса

$data = file("$id.dat"); //читаем содержимое файла результатов и помещаем в массив

// если это не просто просмотр результатов
if ($vote) {

//сравниваем ip с уже записанными
foreach($ip_abbr as $value) 
if ($ip == $value) {echo "<p><b><font color=red> Вы уже голосовали! </font></b></p>";
exit;
}
// выводим благодарность
echo "<p><b><font color=green> Спасибо! </font></b><br /><i>*Показаны результаты до Вашего голосования:</i><p>";
}

// выводим заголовок голосования - 1я строка файла
echo "<b>$data[0]</b><p>";

// печатаем список ответов и результатов - остальные строки
for ($i=1;$i<count($data);$i++) {
  $votes = explode("~", $data[$i]); // значение~ответ
  echo "$votes[1]: <b>$votes[0]</b><br>"; //поменяйте местами 0 и 1 в $votes и в результатах цифры будут первыми
}
echo "<br>Всего проголосовало: <b>".(count($ip_abbr)-1)."</b>";

// если это не просмотр результатов, а голосование,
// производим необходимые действия для учета голоса
if ($vote) {
  $f = fopen("$id.dat","w");
  flock($f,LOCK_EX);
  fputs($f, "$data[0]");
  for ($i=1;$i<count($data);$i++) {
    $votes = explode("~", $data[$i]);
    if ($i==$vote) $votes[0]++;
    fputs($f,"$votes[0]~$votes[1]");
    fflush($f);
flock($f,LOCK_UN);
  }
  fclose($f);

//и записываем ip
  $ip_adr = fopen("ip$id.dat","a++");
    flock($ip_adr,LOCK_EX);
 fputs($ip_adr, "$ip".",");
 fflush($ip_adr);
    flock($ip_adr,LOCK_UN);
fclose($ip_adr);
  }

  } else {
//передан id несуществующего голосования
     echo "Такого голосования не существует.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: а что за `?id=1` у вас в `require_once` ?

Comment: id указывает на сам опрос, то есть если его убрать, то просто будет писать, что такого голосования не существует. Сейчас добавлю файл vote.php, чтобы было нагляднее

Comment: а так пишет что файл не найден. вы разберитесь для начлаа. что такое get-параметры, и где и как они передаются.

Comment: я знаю что такое get параметры) вопрос стоял в том, как сделать роутинг на php в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public function actionIndexvsite()
    {
        require_once(ROOT . '/views/cabinet/vote.php');
        return true;
    }
```

1) Не стоит путать **Url** и **путь до скрипта**

2) Допустим что это даже работало бы, зачем вы передаете get параметр в require_once, если у вас есть суперглобальный масив где он уже есть `$_GET['id'];`

3) Для нормального роутинга реализуйте одну точку входа, в которой регистрируется сам роут и контроллер, ищет подходящий контроллер и передает ему управление.

Comment: спасибо, немного разобрался) правда сейчас выдает просто, что не существует данного голосования, не подскажете, как я могу передать id, чтобы мне по клику на кнопку Голосовать или Результаты открывало информацию о результатах?

Comment: в файле `vote.php` напишите var_dump($_GET); и покажите вывод

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: vote in W:\domains\shop.php-start.com-master\views\cabinet\vote.php on line 3
array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } Такого голосования не существует.

Comment: @quires Только что заметил, вы выждаетесь в двух get параметрах, id и vote, но vote вы нигде не передаете, разберитесь откуда она берется и как вы ее должны передать